# What would cause an XmlException ("Root element is missing") on using JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader with valid Json with a root element?

Tags: xml, json, httpresponse

I am trying to convert JSON to XML using the .Net JsonReaderWriterFactory. The Json I am using is valid (as validated by http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and the conversion of the same JSON works when using JsonConvert, but when attempting to replace the Json.Net functionality with the native .Net functionality (a requirement of where I'm working) I get an XmlException "Root element is missing".

The test JSON I am using is:

```
{
        "customers"    :   [        
    {
        "id":               "b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c1876e5",
        "name":             "",
        "customer_code":    "WALKIN",
        "customer_group_id":         "b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c1840bb",
        "customer_group_name":       "All Customers",
        "updated_at":               "2014-09-26 09:13:47"
    }
,       
    {
        "id":               "b8ca3a6e-72a9-11e4-efc6-455deebc001e",
        "name":             "Caroline Chambers",
        "customer_code":    "Caroline-79T7",
        "customer_group_id":         "b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c1840bb",
        "customer_group_name":       "All Customers",
        "first_name":             "Caroline",
        "last_name":              "Chambers",
        "email":                  "caroline.chambers@hotmail.com",
        "postal_country_id" :     "GB",        
        "updated_at":               "2014-09-26 09:17:26",
        "date_of_birth":            "1980-02-20",
        "sex":                      "F"
    }
,   
    {
        "id":               "b8ca3a6e-72a9-11e4-efc6-455e1b7bcc0f",
        "name":             "Andrew Adamson",
        "customer_code":    "Andrew-85SW",
        "customer_group_id":         "b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c1840bb",
        "customer_group_name":       "All Customers",
        "first_name":             "Andrew",
        "last_name":              "Adamson",
        "email":                  "andrew.adamson@hotmail.com",
        "postal_country_id" :     "GB",
        "updated_at":               "2014-09-26 09:18:41",
        "date_of_birth":            "1980-06-01",
        "sex":                      "M"
    }
    ]
}
```

My code is:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (XmlDictionaryReader xmlReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(dataStream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
    {
        xmlReader.Read();
        document.LoadXml(xmlReader.ReadOuterXml());
    }
}
```

The equivalent, using the same JSON response, with Json.Net works without error:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
    {
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        document = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(responseFromServer, "Root");
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to the response stream before calling CreateJsonReader to create a valid root element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the JsonReaderWriterFactory code **is** working.

I had a line of code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

before the call to JsonReaderWriterFactory in order to output my Json for debugging purposes (line left out of example for simplicity). This meant that when the dataStream was used for the conversion it was empty, having already been read to end. Without that it now works as expected.